# Pentaho BI Marketplace

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to make some changes in my Dashboards with **CDE** .
But when I access Pentaho plateform 5.0 as Admin I can't find the Marketplace in all the menus
Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Marketplace is a perspective in the Pentaho User Console for Pentaho 5, so it should be available on the dropdown on the left top of PUC.

Note, however, that the marketplace is only available on the CE edition. If you're running an EE version, the marketplace is not installed by default.

You can install it, however. Download from here: http://ci.pentaho.com/job/marketplace/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/marketplace-plugin-TRUNK-SNAPSHOT.zip

and unzip into the system folder. Restart the BA Server and you should be all set.

Comment: As of last week, the above link only works for Pentaho 5.2. Please visit http://pentaho.com/marketplace for download links for different versions of the Pentaho Platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download marketplace.

in theory, you should be able to download it from http://pentaho.com/marketplace
BUT currently the link is broken. you can download it manually here:
http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/pentaho/marketplace/6.0-SNAPSHOT/

2. Unzip into /pentaho-solutions/system
3. restart
4. enter PUC (Pentaho User Console)
5. Enter Marketplace from the upper left menu
6. Install CDE/CDA Plugins